# php cron timeout - run script in background

Tags: php, background

i have a script in php `extract_data.php`and it takes 20 minutes to run the script.
I activated cron to run the script. but the cron has a time of only 30 seconds (this time cannot be increased).
the problem is that i always get the timeout error.

I would like it to appear: `file loading...` while the script is running.

i test `exec("extract_data.php"." > /dev/null &");`

does not work

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a default configuration for the timeout.
Please take a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

```
set_time_limit(0); // To run without timeout.
```

Or

```
set_time_limit(20*60); //to allow to run for only 20 minutes
```

Comment: i not search this

Comment: Is it about the timeout for the cronjob itself?

Comment: According to documentation: https://github.com/pschlan/cron-job.org there is some request timeout set for 30 seconds. You are able to change it in the config file: https://github.com/pschlan/cron-job.org/blob/7e251d2d18aaead8e5365daf988ab83d7a55023f/chronos/chronos.cfg